# Downgrading a Universal iOS App to iPad only

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

I have a universal app which I decided should become iPad only from the next version. I already know how to change the target to get the desired effect.
What I don't fully understand is the impact on my users.
Lets say the currently released version number is 1.0 and the updated iPad only version is 2.0. Will my iPhone users see this 2.0 update and start getting errors when they try to download/run the app or will they simply stay forever on version 1.0 without any notification on version 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple won't let you do this. I have tried this by changing an app from universal to iPhone-only and it wasn't possible to submit this app.

Comment: what's the reason Apple gives for not allowing it?

Comment: I think the reason is that it's not user friendly.